# remove item from checklist using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net web page.

I am using the asp.net checkboxlist control.

Is it possible to remove an item using jquery?

I can enumerate through the checked array but cannot seem to remove a checked item.

I have this which does not work:

```
       function ConfirmDialog(message) {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                .html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
                .dialog({
                    modal: true, title: 'Delete', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function () {
                            var selectedItems = "";
                            $("[id*=chkEmailClients] input:checked").each(function () {
                                var emailClient = $(this).next().html();

                                //                                    jQuery(this).closest('chkEmailClients.tr').remove();

                                alert($(this).closest('tr').html());
                                try {
                                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                                    return false;
                                }
                                catch (error) {
                                    alert(error);
                                }
                            });
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
    };
```

This is the DOM stuff:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="chkEmailClients" style="display: inline-block; color: Black; font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 8pt; height: 200px; width: 270px;">
            <input id="chkEmailClients_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_0"
                value="andrew.simpson18@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_0">email1@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_1"
                value="andrew.simpson17@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_1">email2@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_2"
                value="andrew.simpson1712@virginmedia.com"><label for="chkEmailClients_2">email3@virginmedia.com</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_3"
                value="andrew.simpson18@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_3">email4@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_4"
                checked="checked" value="andrew.simpson17@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_4">email5@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_5"
                value="andrew.simpson1712@virginmedia.com"><label for="chkEmailClients_5">email6@virginmedia.com</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_6"
                value="andrew.simpson18@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_6">email7@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_7" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_7"
                value="andrew.simpson17@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_7">email8@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_8" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_8"
                value="andrew.simpson1712@virginmedia.com"><label for="chkEmailClients_8">email9@virginmedia.com</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_9" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_9"
                value="andrew.simpson18@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_9">email10@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_10" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_10"
                value="andrew.simpson17@hotmail.co.uk"><label for="chkEmailClients_10">email11@hotmail.co.uk</label><br>
            <input id="chkEmailClients_11" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkEmailClients$chkEmailClients_11"
                value="andrew.simpson1712@virginmedia.com"><label for="chkEmailClients_11">email12@virginmedia.com</label></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you missing parentheses? Try `alert($(this).closest('tr').html())`

Comment: Hi, I am using this:   alert($(this).closest('tr').html());

Comment: Folks just had a thought and I guess it may be important (sorry) but I will amend my question to show what i mean

Comment: I see, you have updated your question concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net generate a table from your checkboxlist, and in order to remove an option you must remove actually a TR. add this code in loop you have.

```
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 return false;
```

**[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/wDWst/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for replying.  I had seen this elsewhere but could not get it to work.  I have edited my question to show this..

Comment: try alerting the values first.

Comment: Do you mean alert('my value')?

Comment: yes, i did do that and I do get the selected values in my alert box. This is why i am puzzled

Comment: Try alerting $(this).closest('tr') instead

Comment: Hi, I get object [object]

Comment: and for $(this).closest('tr').html

Comment: I did a screenshot above

Comment: i mean for $(this).closest('tr').html()

Comment: can you share the dom of generated checklist

Answer (score 0):

To any one who is interested.  The answers provided by @Milind Anantwar was correct.  I had set the Repeatlayout to flow which meant that the rendered html was in input/label mode.  By changing to table it worked.  I should never program when i am tired